# How to call Html.Display for a custom object, not the whole Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following view-model for my MVC3 Razor view:

```
 public class UserProfileModel
 {
     public Person[] Persons { get; set; }
     //some other fields
 }
```

I want to display all the persons in my Razor view like:

```
foreach (var person in Model.Persons)
{
<div>
    @* some custom formatting *@
    @Html.Display(person)
</div>
}
```

`@Html.Display` or `@Html.DisplayFor` seems to not work for me..

I can create a separate stongly-typed view using `Person` as a model and call `@Html.DisplayForModel` there, but is there a way to go without a separate view?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Create a partial view file called `Person.cshtml` inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`. Make it strongly typed to `Person` class.

Implement the structure of your view.

Then when you call it like below *(on your case)*, you will get what you expected :

```
foreach (var person in Model.Persons)
{
<div>
    @* some custom formatting *@
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => person)
</div>
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I don't need a custom template by the way, I just haven't thought of using `@Html.DisplayFor(m => person)` without using `m => m.Something` :)